# Do every $3$ linearly independent vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given $3$ vectors that are linearly independent.  I am trying to figure our if they span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to declare them as basis.

Comment: I assume you mean, "do EVERY 3 linearly independent vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, because if you just needed to find one set of 3 vectors this would be trivial.  Editing accordingly, please comment if you object.

Comment: @Goos I agree with the edit. thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, because $\mathbb R^3$ is $3$-dimensional (meaning precisely that any three linearly independent vectors span it). To see this, note that if we had $3$ linearly independent vectors which did not span $\mathbb R^3$, we could expand this to a collection of $4$ linearly independent vectors. Writing these in a matrix and performing row-reduction shows that this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Your vectors span a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ of dimension $3$.

Since the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is $3$ we conclude this
subspace is all of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

**ADDED:** I have used the claim that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector
space, $S$ is a sub vector space with $\dim(S)=\dim(V)$, then $S=V$.

I did not include a proof for this, as I assumed it to be known (thus
my answer is, as pointed out in the comments, is not self-contained).

Comment: I actually don't buy this argument.  Try it with $\mathbb{R}^3$ replaced by the vector space $\mathbb{R}[t]$ and its dimension $\aleph_0$: it doesn't work.  We need some argument particular to the finite-dimensional case to tell us that we can't have a proper inclusion of vector spaces of the same dimension.  (Possible arguments include row-reduction and the Steinitz Exchange Lemma.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark - I believe that most of the basic linear algebra courses only treat the case of finite dimensional vector spaces (at least this is the case whre I study). It is often proved in those courses the property I used

Comment: I agree with both of the things you said.  In fact the OP's question is certainly addressed in any basic linear algebra course, so in some sense a correct answer would be to refer him to the notes/text/videos of such a course.  But it looks like you are claiming a self-contained proof of the result.  I noted that your assertion doesn't hold in the infinite-dimensional case as proof that your argument is not in fact self-contained: something must be missing.  If you don't in fact purport to give a self-contained proof, that's fine but it would be nice if you said so in your answer.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark -I have edited accordingly. I'm sorry I didn't do this earlier, my
finals just started and I was incredibly busy. Thanks for pointing
that out (I admit that at the time I didn't notice that myself , so
your comment helped me understand what I was using and recall where
it holds)